# How to generate Poissonian Gaussian distribution from sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to generate a Poissonian-Gaussian distribution with $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma) + \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$, from sum of independent random variable: 
$Z = \sum_i{X_i}$. 
Is there any easy known form for random variables $X_i$ so that summing them up will result in a poissonian-gaussian distribution ? In other words, I am looking for family of distribution that, summing them will result in my desired Poissonian-Gaussian distribution.

Note that in problem there is a constant number of the random variables $X_i$, lets say $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$. All of them must have the same distribution.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... why wouldn't you just take $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent, where $X_1$ is normal and $X_2$ is Poisson?

Comment: ok, I see; I am not clear enough. I added more explanation. Thanks!
I need to have the same distribution for all of the $X_i$ independent random variables.

Comment: Well, clearly, if each $X_i$ is itself of the form $Z_i+N_i$ (resp. Gaussian and Poisson) and they are independent, the sum of the $X_i$'s will also be "poissonian-gaussian".

Comment: I don't think that would be true. Sum of random variables means convolution of distributions. Sum of Gaussians are Gaussians, and sum of Poissons are Poisson; but convolution of a Gaussian with Poisson?

Comment: Wait — I assumed that by $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma) + \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ you meant "$Z=X+Y$, with $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$". Isn't it the case? Because if so, if $X_i=Z_i+N_i$, then $$\sum_i X_i = \underbrace{\sum_i Z_i}_{\text{Gaussian}} + \underbrace{\sum_i N_i}_{\text{Poisson}}$$

Comment: @ClementC. is right--or I understand nothing in this question.

Comment: Oh no; All I am saying is that $$Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma) + \mathcal{P}(\lambda) \; (1) $$. And I am looking for analytic (or approximate) form for $X_i$, all with the same distribution for $i=1,...,N$,  such that $Z = \sum_i{X_i}$ will give the desired result in Eq (1).

Comment: Daniel: Do we agree this question is answered? Then you could write down a solution yourself, post it, and after a while, accept it.

Comment: Well, not really. I don't see any acceptable solutions in this page.